# How to make an animation start when you stop hovering over text?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I would be really happy if anyone could help me.

I'm making a navigation bar for a website and I made an animation that when you hover over a link it slowly transitions color. I made it with CSS keyframes. Does anyone know how to make it that when you stop hovering over it, it will again slowly transition back to base color instead of just changing in a moment.
Thanks for all the answers in advance.

Comment: Post relevant code in the question

Comment: Also this could be done via a simple `transition` property instead of keyframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will transform the green text to black slowly:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
#h1 {
    color: green;
    transition: all 2s linear;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#h1:hover {
    color: black;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<h1 id="h1">hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Before hovering:

[image]

After hovering:

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want that when I hover over my text it changes color slowly and when is move my mouse away from it (stop hovering) it slowly changes its color back to the color it was before I started hovering.

Comment: thts it the original color is green and when you hover it it becomes black
and when mouse is not hovering its goes back to original color

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't slowly transition back to the original color as it went from the original color to black

Comment: which browser do u use

Comment: I use opera gx.

Comment: maybe tht browser doesnt support that animation try using Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome or any other chromium based Web Browser

Comment: ok I will try now

Comment: your welcome.
Not all browsers support html5 and css3